# Sound icon not working

Tags: icons, pulseaudio, alsa, volume-control, indicator-sound

I am using Ubuntu 13.04. last time i installed Pulse-audio-4.0 after which a weird problem started with my sound icon.In sound icon there are two hyphens following the speaker like <|-- 
i clicked to open it .the trigger is always set to zero and it is stuck there, i can't move it. I opened sound from setting , i don't see any audio device listed.
But applications are working and there is no problem with audio output.

But when i log out at log in , everything becomes normal. My audio device gets listed, 
volume tray is responding and i can control volume via that trigger.

The problem returns after reboot, i had to log and log out every time.

Please tell me how to get it fixed permanently!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptom plus I was getting crashes in Saucy.  See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-sound/+bug/1208204.

There is a patch in message #5 that might help you.  Reboot after applying the patch.  It solved both of my issues.

Good luck.